# pull after rebase results into merging conflicts

Tags: git, rebase, pull

I have a branch B, that was checked out in another repo, then some changes were done there and after rebase they were push'ed with --force (it was a fixup to the last commit).
Now, if I pull the changed branch into the first repo, I get merging conflicts.

The commands I run (with irrelevant changes, that simplify the actual output) are as follows:

```
#   First checkout the original B
$ pwd
/home/user/dir1

$ git checkout B
Switched to branch 'B'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/B'.

#   Now clone the same repo into another directory and checkout B there
$ cd .. && git clone git clone ssh://git@myhost/myrepo.git dir2 && cd dir2

$ git checkout B
Switched to branch 'B'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/B'.

#   Now edit some file, commit it and "merge" the changes
#   to the originally last commit as a fixup
$ nano file.txt
$ git commit -a -m "Fixup to file.txt"
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2
... the last commit is "fixup'ed" to the last commit in the original branch (the commit before "Fixup to the file.txt" commit

#   Push the B with rewritten history to the upstream
$ git push --force origin B

#   Get back to the original repo and pull the changes
$ cd ../dir1
$ git pull origin B
...
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in .../file.txt
...
```

The only difference between the two copies of the branch is in the "top" commit.
Is it possible to tell git, that I want to replace the last commit in the first repo with what I have in the upstream without git-pull trying to look inside for changes in the corresponding files?

Comment: Can you rephrase the question and use names for branches, remotes and important commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a history like

```
...-A-B-C-D-E     # HEAD
```

Where `E` is the unchanged commit in `dir/`. We will introduce `E'` as a commit that originated from `E` but was rebased and force-pushed from `dir2`.

In `dir` you can rewind your `HEAD` to be on the prior commit:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

to get

```
...-A-B-C-D        # HEAD
           \
            `-E    # dangling and invisible, will be garbage collected
```

afterwards

```
git pull upstream B
```

will give you whatever was there

```
...-A-B-C-D-E'     # HEAD
           \
            `-E    # dangling and invisible, will be garbage collected
```

Be warned though, you will lose the content of `E` (unless you search for it in `reflog`)

Comment: well, all the content, that matters was pushed to the upstream from the second copy. So, the only thing I need is getting the same data in the first branch as in the second and in the upstream.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question. See my other comment.